# Type annotation breaks function

Tags: haskell

Consider the following declarations for a function f' using singletons with the Frames library (which defines UnColumn and AllAre), and a wrapper function using withSing.

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes -#}
import Frames
import Data.Singletons.Prelude

f' ::  forall rs1 rs2 a. (AllAre a (UnColumn rs1), AllAre a (UnColumn rs2), Num a)
      => SList rs1 -> SList rs2 -> Frame (Record rs1) -> Frame (Record rs2) -> Int
f' = undefined

f df1 df2 = withSing (withSing f') df1 df2
```

This seems to work fine. But when I add a type annotation, type checking fails with the error Could not deduce: `(AllAre a0 (UnColumn rs1), AllAre a0 (UnColumn rs2))`.

```
f :: (SingI rs1, SingI rs2, AllAre a (UnColumn rs2), AllAre a (UnColumn rs1), Num a)
=> Frame (Record rs1) -> Frame (Record rs2) -> Int
f df1 df2 = withSing (withSing f') df1 df2
```

The thing is, this is precisely the *inferred* type signature, according to GHCi (well, Intero). To my understanding adding an explicit signature matching the inferred signature should have no impact on the code semantics, so why would this break the code?

Comment: What is `a`? Seems to be ambiguous.

Comment: It's something with a Num instance.  I left out a few constraints for readability, but I can see why the declaration doesn't make much sense without some other constraint on a.  I edited it back in.

Comment: The `a` should be somehow linked to the type after the `=>` (or at least the code itself, with some extensions on), otherwise GHC will always be unable to understand how to use such `a` -- it will continue inferring another type variable `a0` instead, and complain that it can't deduce the needed constraints on `a0`. It can be puzzling at the beginning, but that's how it has to work. After all, `f` could call `f'` on a _different_ type than `a`.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know what specifc `a` to use. This might be important, because the choice of `a` will determine the choice of some class instances, which will have an effect on the meaning of the program. Of course, it might also _not_ matter if all classes involved are trivial or empty, but the compiler doesn't know that, only you do.

Comment: Still, it works fine as long as I don't write the type signature.  This is a minimal example based on a (working) real function that multiplies two frames that have (AllAre a .., Num a).  I believe that the type a is inferred from the AllAre constraints and the type of frames passed in.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour - `f'` doesn't compile with a bunch of ambiguous type errors related precisely to the type `a`. (NB: I've added the imports I needed to get it to compile; if these are not the right ones, please correct). I'm guessing you have `AllowAmbiguousTypes` enabled, which makes `f'` compile. To get `f` to compile, enable `TypeApplications` and `ScopedTypeVariables`, add a `forall rs1 rs2 a . {..}` to the type of `f`, and change `f'` in the body of `f` to `f' @_ @_ @a`. I'm not actually sure what cleverness the compile does to figure it out w/o a type signature.

Comment: @user2407038 You are correct - AllowAmbiguousTypes is on and without this extension the code won't type check with or without the type annotation.  I've added this to the question. And I confirm that your changes with TypeApplications make it compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a **general rule of thumb**, adding an explicit type signature that matches the inferred type to a Haskell program will not change its meaning, but it's not actually guaranteed in the general case.  (I believe it *is* guaranteed for top-level definitions in Haskell98, though.)

Ultimately, your problem isn't much different from the sort of type variable scoping problem that can happen with local definitions in Haskell98:

```
import Data.List
sortImage :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]
sortImage f = sortBy cmp
  where cmp x y = compare (f x) (f y)
```

Here, the inferred type of `cmp` is effectively `(Ord b) => a -> a -> Ordering`.  You can't make this signature explicit, though, because you can't tie `a` and `b` back to the outer signature (and the type of `f` in particular) unless you use `ScopedTypeVariables`, in which case you can write:

```
sortImage :: forall a b . Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]
sortImage f = sortBy cmp
  where cmp :: a -> a -> Ordering
        cmp x y = compare (f x) (f y)
```

As you've discovered, you can make this sort of type variable scoping problem happen with top level definitions, too, at least with `AllowAmbiguousTypes` enabled.

Here is a simpler example that illustrates what I believe is the same problem, adapted from the GHC documentation on the `AllowAmbiguousTypes` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

class D a b
instance D Bool b
instance D Int b

strange :: D a b => a -> a
strange = undefined

-- stranger :: (D a b1, D a b) => a -> a
stranger x = strange (strange x)
```

I've shown the inferred type of `stranger` as a comment.  If you try to make it explicit, you'll get the error:

> • Could not deduce (D a b0) arising from a use of ‘strange’
>     from the context: (D a b2, D a b)

The issue is that GHC can infer that `stranger` can be called on any `a` that satisfies `D a b1` for the outer `strange :: D a b1 => a -> a` and also satisfies `D a b` for the inner `strange :: D a b => a -> a`.

However, if you attempt to make this type signature explicit, the link between the `b1` and `b` variables in the explicit signature for `stranger` and their relationship to the types of the `strange` calls is lost, much as the relationship between the `a` and `b` in a hypothetical `cmp` signature and the `a` and `b` in the `sortImage` signature is lost in the first example.

Using `ScopedTypeVariables` alone isn't enough to solve the problem here because, constraints aside, the type of `strange` is just `a -> a` and doesn't directly reference `b`.  So, you can write:

```
stranger :: forall a b1 b2 . (D a b1, D a b2) => a -> a
stranger x = (strange :: a -> a) ((strange :: a -> a) x)
```

but you can't tie the `b1` and `b2` to the types of the `strange` calls.  You need `TypeApplications` to do that:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

class D a b
instance D Bool b

strange :: forall a b . D a b => a -> a
strange = id

stranger :: forall a b1 b2 . (D a b1, D a b2) => a -> a
stranger x = (strange @a @b1) (strange @a @b2 x)
```

and then it type checks okay, and you can even call:

```
> stranger False
False
```

without any type annotations (which is somewhat surprising).  If you had an instance:

```
instance D Int Double
```

though, then you'd need to be explicit to use `stranger` on `Int`s:

```
> stranger @_ @Double @Double (1 :: Int)
```